# AssociationTypeMismatch in Rails/GraphQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

So my data is pretty simple. Books and Users.

```
class Books
 belongs_to :user
end

class Users
 has_many :books
end
```

Users has the following fields:

```
first_name
last_name
email
```

Books has the following fields:

```
author
title
description
```

My book_type looks like:

```
Types::BookType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
 name 'Book'
field :id, !types.ID
field :author, !types.String
field :title, !types.String
field :user, -> {Types::UserType}, property: :user
end
```

User_type looks like:

```
Types::UserType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
 name 'User'
 field :id, !types.ID
 field :first_name, !types.String
 field :last_name, !types.String
 field :email, !types.String
end
```

Mutation_type looks like:

```
Types::MutationType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
 name 'Mutation'
 field :bookCreate, function: Resolvers::BookCreate.new
end
```

Book_create file looks like:

```
class Resolvers::BookCreate < GraphQL::Function
 argument :author, !types.String
 argument :title, !types.String
 argument :description, !types.String
 argument :user, !types.Int

 type Types::BookType

 def call(_obj, args, _ctx)
  Book.create!(
   author: args[:author],
   title: args[:title],
   description: args[:description],
   user: args[:user]
   )
 end
end
```

Then in localhost:3000/graphiql I do the following:

```
mutation book {
 bookCreate(
  author: "Test", 
  title: "Book Test", 
  description: "Book Description", 
  user: 2) {
 id
 author
 title
 description
 }
}
```

Getting the following:

```
<ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#69982231587660) expected, got 2 which is an instance of Integer(#11387600)>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Looks like the field should be `user_id` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed user to user_id and then on the book model did:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id'
```

Now it works.